# Linkedlist remove method erroe

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

when i try to remove element there is an error, i have uploaded the error in the image section. any help to fix? of any other way to get the code fixed and working smoothly and it it works while deleting the middle element not the first or second
duplication issue ,fixed using iterator. hatsooff to stack overflow .
all good

```
import java.util.*;

public class EarthquakeList {
private ArrayList<EarthquakeNode> records;

public EarthquakeList() {
   records = new ArrayList<EarthquakeNode>();

}

public boolean isempty() {
      return true;
}


public void add(String EarthquakeLo,String EarthquakeDt, double EarthquakeSgth, int EarthquakeDu) {
   EarthquakeNode en = new EarthquakeNode(EarthquakeLo, EarthquakeDt, EarthquakeSgth, EarthquakeDu);
   records.add(en);
}


public boolean remove(String EarthquakeLo,String EarthquakeDt) {
   boolean flag= false;
   for(EarthquakeNode earthquake: records)
   {
       if(earthquake.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(EarthquakeLo))
       {
           if(earthquake.getDate().equals(EarthquakeDt))
           {
               records.remove(earthquake);
               flag=true;

           }
       }
   }
   return flag;
 }


 public EarthquakeNode search(String EarthquakeLo,String EarthquakeDt) {
   EarthquakeNode node= null;
   for(EarthquakeNode earthquake: records)
   {
       if(earthquake.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(EarthquakeLo))
       {
           if(earthquake.getDate().equals(EarthquakeDt))
           {

               node=earthquake;
           }
       }
   }
   return node;
}


public boolean clear() {

   int count=records.size();
   for(EarthquakeNode earthquake: records)
   {
       count=count-1;
       records.remove(earthquake);



   }
   if(count==0)
   {
   System.out.println("already empty");
   return false;}

   else 
   System.out.println("every thing is removed");
   return true;
}


public boolean isempty(String EarthquakeLo,String EarthquakeDt) {
   boolean flag= false;
   for(EarthquakeNode earthquake: records)
   {
       if(earthquake.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(EarthquakeLo))
       {
           if(earthquake.getDate().equals(EarthquakeDt))
           {
               flag=true;
           }
       }
   }
   return flag;
}


public void print() {
   for(EarthquakeNode earthquake: records)
   {
       System.out.println( earthquake.getLocation() +" - "
              + earthquake.getDate()+ " - "
               + earthquake.getStrength() + " on rector scale"+
               "-" + earthquake.getDuration() + "mins");
   }

}


}
```

Comment: Please don't take an image of your error and post a link to it.  It is much better to copy/paste the text of the error (and to point out which line the exception occurred on).

Comment: @rmlan  how can i fix that ?

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions : attributes, variables, parameters, method have to start in lowerCase

Comment: By following the answers in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an Iterator to safely remove from a collection while iterating over it.

```
public boolean remove(String earthquakeLo, String earthquakeDt) {
   boolean flag= false;
   Iterator<EarthquakeNode> iterator = records.iterator();
   while(iterator.hasNext()) {
      EarthquakeNode earthquake = iterator.next();
      if(earthquake.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(earthquakeLo)) {
           if(earthquake.getDate().equals(earthquakeDt)) {
              iterator.remove();
              flag=true;
           }
      }
   }
   return flag;
 }
```

Comment: works perfect with 3 elements.. if i add 4th element the same error occur

Comment: when i add the 4th element :(                                                     true
  -- Removing a specific record --
node to be deleted location : EarthquakeNode@70dea4e
AUSTRALIA - 10/4/2002 - 2.0 on rector scale-5mins
GERMANY - 01/8/2016 - 6.0 on rector scale-10mins
AUS - 11/4/2020 - 2.0 on rector scale-5mins
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
 at EarthquakeList.clear(EarthquakeList.java:61)
 at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:17)

Comment: the same ConcurrentModificationError?

Comment: yeah for clear method   ... trying to fix java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: using Iterator for removing elements you shouldnt have the ConcurrentModificationException problems... very strange...

Comment: works perfect.... changed  the clear method

Comment: public boolean clear() {
      
       int count=records.size();
     
       Iterator<EarthquakeNode> iterator = records.iterator();
       while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        EarthquakeNode earthquake = iterator.next();
        count=count-1;
        iterator.remove();
       
       }
       if(count==0)
       {
       System.out.println("already empty");
       return false;}
       
       else 
       System.out.println("every thing is removed"); 
       records=null;
       return true;
   }